# Efficient way to transpose large dataset in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
A  B
1  2
1  3
1  4
5  8
5  9
5  10
```

and I want an output as follows:

```
  B
A 2  3  4 8 9 10
1 1  1  1 0 0 0 
5 0  0  0 1 1 1
```

is there a package that can create an "indicator matrix"? The real data set has about 300,000,000 rows and 2 columns. The value in column B are actually variables, and I want to create a data set to indicate whether than variable is "turned on".

Comment: `table(mydf)` should get you most of the way.

Comment: If I do table(mydf) I get an error: Error in table(train) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements.

Comment: If it is all integers convert it to the matrix.

Comment: I am using data.table package and I want to keep it that data type

Comment: using `data.table` you can do something like `dcast(dt, A~B, fun.aggregate=length)`

Comment: Why transpose at all? Just `dt[, .N, by = list(A, B)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5), B = c(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10))
table(df)
```

If you have other columns in the data frame, and you want to only use columns A, B , you can use this way:

```
table(df$A, df$B)
```

You can save this table as its own data frame by converting the table output above to data frame as follows:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(df$A, df$B))
```

Comment: I reach my system's memory limits when I try to create a data frame. Are there any other ways you can do this, or is R not suitable to handle very large datasets.

Comment: It does not seem to be an R problem, but the problem with available memory on your system. Quite possible that you don't have enough for this size data summarization.

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM. So are there any alternatives or do I need to buy a better computer?

Comment: This is not a good answer since the question states 'efficient way to transpose'; this means that there should be a function or method to transpose without requiring massive amounts of RAM (hence the 'efficient' part). This answer doesn't provide an alternative method to accomplish this nor an explanation why it may be impossible.